# Launch a program running on the server

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a php file running all the time on my server, checking every second if there are changes in my inbox.

To to that, I've coded a while loop like I show:

```
/folder1/page/test.php:

session_start();
    while (true){
      set_time_limit(0);
      date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
      require_once ('./folder1/path.php');
      require_once ( CLASSES . 'Builder.php');          
      $UIModules = Builder::getUIModules();
          $current_items = $UIModules->getfile();
      sleep(1);
    }
```

So in SSH, I launch my file with php5.4 as I show `/usr/bin/php5.4 /kunden/homepages/31/d466491669/htdocs/folder1/page/test.php`.

It gives me back this error: "No Input File Specified". I've tried to solve it by adding an .htaccess file with these 3 rows but still the same issue:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Following the question that started at the beginning, I also want to ask if it's possible to call a cron.php on my root, as this style:

```
while (true){
   set_time_limit(0);
   if (strpos( __DIR__ ,'d466491669') == true)
      require_once ('./folder1/page/test.inc.php');
   else
      require_once (__DIR__ . './page/test.inc.php');
}
```

so I can remove the loop on test.php

Answer (score 0):

When you run PHP as CLI(Command Line Interface) it's totally different than running from browser throu apache/nginex/others_web_server
You can see it by `phpinfo();` on both calles.

here is link for some explanations http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php

Also if you want to run php by cron, then remember it will be run EACH time cron works - so if you set cron job to execute each 2 minutes. Each two minutes your test.php file would be run by `php5.4 -f test.php`. And you want to add some failsafe to that - like locking files or anything to know if last copy of cron job is still working - if it is - `exit`, if not - then work.

*INFORMATION*: .htaccess is totally ignored by php cli. Its only used when request is made through apache or other server application, not the command line interface.  Even *better* this interface have its own `php.ini` file with settings that are slightly different from ,,normal'' configuration file.